# How can I export multiple images and strings to a single file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, file, directory

I'm creating an application that needs to export a few images and a few strings. It currently exports to a folder, but I want to be able to export all of these into a single file. How can I store all this information when the size and quantity of images varies?  I've read a few articles, but they don't say how to store the strings.  I do not want to use a database.

Comment: Must admit that I think both answers are overkill. Why not just "serialize" the images and strings to a byte array yourself, encoding the strings in UTF-8 and the images as PNG file data. It'd be a tiny bit messy to code, but you'd avoid dependencies on zip routines and serialization/deserialization routines that aren't your own.

Comment: Just... I think that it would be easier to do the .ZIP file idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a compressed folder archive?  Save everything as you currently do into a folder, but zip or tar or otherwise compress the folder into a single archive file.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a class with properties to hold the images and strings, you can use `binary serialization` to persist them to a single file. Then you can use deserialization to re-load everything into a new class instance when you want to use them again.

This article will give you an idea (it is in C#)

http://techisolutions.blogspot.co.nz/2008/03/serialization-of-image-c.html